# How to use a here document in a loop?

Tags: bash, shell

This works:

```
name="test.txt"

yap -q << % > $name
  [experiment_yap],
  exp1_min(brother,2).
%
```

This does not:

```
for i in 01 02 03 04 05
do
  name="test.txt"

  yap -q << % > $name
    [experiment_yap],
    exp1_min(brother,2).
  %
done
```

I receive line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not being in a loop that's significant here. `bash` doesn't really know or care about indentation -- to recognize the end of the heredoc the terminating string *must* be at the beginning of the line, which makes your loop look like:

```
for i in 01 02 03 04 05
do
  name="test.txt"

  yap -q << % > $name
    [experiment_yap],
    exp1_min(brother,2).
%
done
```

Comment: If you use `<< -%`, you can indent the body of the here document and the delimiter with tabs (not just arbitrary whitespace). (The body doesn't matter as much, as long as the consumer doesn't care about the leading whitespace.)