# Weird cat behaviour

Tags: bash, function, eof, cat

inside of a function, I would have had multiple echos, but I remembered I could do `cat << EOF` followed by my text to output, followed by EOF. However, it only seems to work when the EOF part is not indented, like this

```
init(){
    if [ conditionial ]; then
        cat << EOF
        this is some text
        this is more text
        this is even more text
```

`EOF`

but it doesn't work like this:

`init(){
        if [ conditionial ]; then
            cat << EOF
            this is some text
            this is more text
            this is even more text
            EOF`

Any ideas?

Comment: It's called a "heredoc" and that's the correct behavior

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a here document in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410005/how-to-use-a-here-document-in-a-loop)

Comment: Working as designed... You might want to read `man bash`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax error: unexpected end of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282533/syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)

Answer (score 2):

"Here document" terminators must appear at the beginning of the line, unless the redirection operator has a `-` suffix:

```
cat << END
this does not
  END
here, but rather here
END
```

vs:

```
cat <<- END
this one does end here
        END
```

(watch out for spaces vs tabs; and some older shell variants do not support this).

Besides these, another useful trick is the handling of expansions inside here documents.  If the end word (`END` in my examples above, `EOF` in yours) is quoted, expansion is inhibited:

```
cat << E1
you are in a maze of twisty little directories: $PWD
E1
cat << 'E2'
you owe the Usenet Oracle $1.75 for the Tab.
E2
```

Answer (score 0):

I never knew this till you asked, but you can use `<<-` (note the `-`) to ignore leading *tabs* (not spaces).

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells)

Answer (score 0):

The `EOF` has to in the beginning of the line and It cant't have anything after it but end of line:

```
#! /bin/bash
function say_hello {
        cat << EOF
        hello
        world
EOF
}
```

Execution:

```
bash test.sh
        hello
        world
```

Taking a closer look with `cat -A`:

```
cat -A  test.sh
#! /bin/bash$
$
function say_hello {$
^Icat << EOF$
^Ihello$
^Iworld$
EOF$
}$
$
say_hello$
```

I had problem with script which would have space after `EOF` and would not work, only with `cat -A` I could identify the space.